# Whirlpool washing machine has a small leak from bottom

Tags: water, leak, washing-machine

I have replaced the seal below the pump and the drain hose and I have a leak only on normal when it's operating in spin cycle. It's a small leak on the front bottom counter weight. Can anyone help? I have checked and the seal below is on very well. I thought this was the problem from the beginning, but I guess not!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only on spin, when water is being drained, check out the whole length of the drain hose *while the machine is on spin and draining*... the drip could be from where it enters the waste pipe, from the hose itself, or from the connection under the tub.

Also, search online specifying the washer make and model, as well as "drain leak", as it might be a well-known issue.